# Reorder items in Apache Wicket's repeating views

Tags: wicket

Is it possible to reorder items that have been added to a repeating view (more precisely a `ListView`) in Apache Wicket?

I tried reordering them in the attached list, like shown in the following code, but this had no effect:

```
int indexA = itemList.indexOf(itemA);
int indexB = itemList.indexOf(itemB);
itemList.set(indexA, itemB);
itemList.set(indexB, itemA);
```

As this had no effect I  tried resetting the list property of the `ListView`:

```
listView.setList(itemList);
```

Of course I remembered to trigger an according repaint for the web page, but all in all it had no effect.

In some further attempts I tried to add a new item not to the end of the list but to the beginning:

```
itemList.add(0, newItem);
```

Instead of just

```
itemList.add(newItem);
```

While the latter one works (and always worked fine), the first obviously works for the first item but throws an exception for the second item.

```
Last cause: Unable to find component with id 'list-component' in [ListItem [Component id = 0]]
    Expected: 'list-container:list-items:0:list-component'.
    Found with similar names: 'list-container:list-items:1:list-component'
```

Where `list-container` is the `WebMarkupContainer` surrounding the `ListView`, `list-items` is the `ListView` itself and `list-component` is the id of the item to be added.

So, is it not possible to reorder items after they have been added to a repeating view? Can new items only be added at the end of it? Or am I missing something here, probably a class different than  `ListView` that implements such features?

My main goal is to be able to reorder items, the "add at the beginning"-approach was just a test if it would at least work to remove the items from the view and re-add them at the desired position.

Comment: Did you pass the list directly to the listview? Or did you use a model? If you use a model the view will update if you refresh the page.

Comment: btw ListView has methods to create 'move Up' and 'move Down' links as well

Comment: I pass it directly, but as I stated, it is not a matter of not refreshing the page, even when I reorder the items in the list as stated above and then manually press F5, the items are not reordered on the web page. Links for moving the items won't help me, the event is triggered elsewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The link that has 'move Up' works like this, you could use this as inspiration :)

```
public final Link<Void> moveUpLink(final String id, final ListItem<T> item)
    {
        return new Link<Void>(id)
        {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            /**
             * @see org.apache.wicket.markup.html.link.Link#onClick()
             */
            @Override
            public void onClick()
            {
                final int index = item.getIndex();
                if (index != -1)
                {

                    addStateChange();

                    // Swap items and invalidate listView
                    Collections.swap(getList(), index, index - 1);
                    ListView.this.removeAll();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isEnabled()
            {
                return item.getIndex() != 0;
            }
        };
    }
```

Comment: Indeed, `itemList.removeAll()` did the trick. Would have never guessed to use that method, thanks.